# Bot (Google Assistant Action) with GPay interface with Stripe - NIGHTMARE

Tags: actions-on-google, google-pay

Let us explain better the situation. The facts are:

- We have a Bot (Google Assitant Action) with a full purchase flow with GPay payment.
- the Bot is already deployed to Beta
- We have a Stripe Account set up and we have got all the private and public keys
- On testing a full flow with GPay payment we have got this log error message on every attempt to perform a transaction:

  ```
  "To use Google Pay for your transactions, you would need to first register at https://services.google.com/fb/forms/googlepayAPIenable/. If this is just for testing, please enable sandbox mode in the Actions simulator."
  ```
- Following the instructions, we have completed the Busniess Profile, and then we jump into the Integration set up. The options available are Android App, Web and Direct Integration. So as we are not integrating nor Android App neither website we assume we neet to select Direct integration.
- So as we are using a "Supported payment provider" we skip the section as indicated.

The result is that the "Submit For Approval" option never gets enabled.

Is anybody having this issue? How to achieve the GPay-Stripe connection for Google Action Bot?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help, 
Aurelio

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Google is working with a limited number of partners that can get access to the production Google Pay API. If you're not one of those partners, you're welcome to read the documentation and test the integration using the sandbox environment.

https://developers.google.com/assistant/transactions/physical/dev-guide-physical-gpay